# Is there a way to run a SQL on excel to create another table on the same spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, sql, tablet

I have a spreadsheet on Microsoft Excel with a formmated table similar to the attached picture. It is a long table (1000 lines or more) with ~30 columns and I would like to know if there is an easy way to create another table from this original table, by applying some filters and aggregating some columns? I have experience working with SQL and if it is possible to configure a `SQL` query on it, it would be perfect, but I don't know if it is possible or how to do it. Is it possible? Thank you.

Example table:

[image]

Result table (aggregate Role columns and sum each month).

[image]

Comment: easiest would be to just carete a pivot table, no sql involved.

Comment: Excel doesn't interface with SQL. It uses VBA, but it's not an easy task.

Comment: You would have to dump it to CSV and import it into access.  Then do the query, and then export/save the results back to csv.  Opening the CSV back up in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @gns100, you insert a pivot table (Insert -> Pivot Table). Then, set the columns, rows and values as shown on the image (drop the months to the Values section, then rename them if necessary (I did)).

[image]

A second possibility is to use Power Query. Data -> Get & Transform -> From Table. When the editor opens, click on "Group by", then Advanced. Set the grouping as shown below. Click OK. Then click on Close and Load.

[image]

[image]

A new table will be inserted.

[image]

A third possibility is to use SUMIF function to calculate the total based on roles and months as criteria.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore it in order to create this table. IIf I change the data on the original table, does it update the pivot table?

Comment: @FelipeOriani Yes, it should. There is also a Refresh button.